# Cakephp2 - Ovrride HttpException wih custom class

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

The default behaviour of CakePhp exception is that a message can be passed and that message is displayed on the name and message key. I want to extend this functionality and display different values for the message and the name key, when an exception is thrown. Furthermore, I want to provide a set of custom fields from time to time.

To achieve this, I created a custom ExceptionRenderer in cakephp, it works fine when cakeexception is thrown and an array is passed, but if I pass an array to an HTTPException inherited excetpion such as NotFoundException, it throws an error.

To achieve this I am thinking to override the default HTTPException class that cakephp has, but am unable to do so. I would like to know how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Hm.. this is a little bit tricky...

You could create a folder inside you App directory with the name Error.

Copy this [file](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.8.2/lib/Cake/Error/exceptions.php) inside there and then inside your `bootstrap.php` replace the line

`require CAKE . 'Error' . DS . 'exceptions.php';`

with

`require APP . DS . 'Error' . DS . 'exceptions.php';`

Then you can start altering the exceptions in the way you like.

This maybe doable but it might have some side effects. For example if the original file is updated on the repository you might have to update your file manually. Also you have to limit your changes to the Exception classes since you don't know where these class might be used inside the core and you might brake something.

Mainly don't change their signatures.